# Force AutoComplete ListBox in a DataGridView on CellEnter

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, autocomplete, listbox

I have a DataGridView with a TextBox column (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn). I already set the AutoCompleteDataSource to a list of string values. Now, the default behavior of the TextBox column is to ONLY show the AutoComplete ListBox when something is typed. Is there a way to show/drop that ListBox on the CellEnter event or as soon as a user highlights that cell?

NOTE: I don't want to use a ComboBox (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) in that column. I have my reasons for that :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK So apparently there isn't a way to do that. So what I did was to just create a ListBox control and show it with the DataSource I wanted displayed. Then handle the associated events.

Please let me know if there's an easier way to do this.

Thanks